# EclipseLink composite persistence units on different servers without <jar-file>

Tags: persistence, eclipselink

My question is almost answered in this thread:

[EclipseLink, EntityManager with two persistence units needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742338/eclipselink-entitymanager-with-two-persistence-units-needed)

But I was using one persistence.xml file to declare 3 persistence units and it worked fine. But now i need a composite persistence unit and I don't know and don't want to build seperate jars for each persistence unit. Is there any way to do this without `<jar-file>` tag. If no, can anyone give me an example of how to make a jar file with a single persistence unit?

**EDIT 1:**
This configuration I ended up with, but it still doesn't work - all I get is this output and when I try to use em.createNamedQuery (witch worked before when I had seperate persistence units) nothing happens the code stops on createEntity line and thats it.

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.composite-unit" value="true"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
    <persistence-unit name="Minutis" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>database.entity.Entity1</class>
    <class>database.entity.Entity2</class>
    ...
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.composite-unit.member" value="true"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
  <persistence-unit name="Minutis2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>database.entity.EEntity1</class>
    <class>database.entity.EEntity2</class>
    ...
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.composite-unit.member" value="true"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
  <persistence-unit name="Minutis3" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>database.entity.EEEntity1</class>
    <class>database.entity.EEEntity2</class>
    ...
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.composite-unit.member" value="true"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This is how `EntityManager` is created:

```
Map minutis = new HashMap();
minutis.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", "user");
minutis.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", "password");
minutis.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "driver");
minutis.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "url");

Map minutis2= new HashMap();
minutis2.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", "user");
minutis2.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", "password");
minutis2.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "driver");
minutis2.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "url");

Map minutis3= new HashMap();
minutis3.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", "user");
minutis3.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", "password");
minutis3.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "driver");
minutis3.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "url");

Map persistanceUnitsProps = new HashMap();
persistanceUnitsProps.put("Minutis", minutis);
persistanceUnitsProps.put("Minutis2", minutis2);
persistanceUnitsProps.put("Minutis3", minutis3);

Map props = new HashMap();
props.put("eclipselink.logging.level", "FINEST");
props.put("eclipselink.composite-unit.properties", persistanceUnitsProps);

EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceUnit", props);
em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

And here is an output that I get:

```
run:
[EL Finest]: 2012-10-09 09:04:43.071--SessionBroker(2079047885)--Thread(Thread[SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1,5,main])--Begin predeploying Persistence Unit persistenceUnit; session file:/C:/Users/Minutis/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication4/build/classes/_persistenceUnit; state Initial; factoryCount 0
[EL Finest]: 2012-10-09 09:04:43.099--SessionBroker(2079047885)--Thread(Thread[SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1,5,main])--property=eclipselink.orm.throw.exceptions; default value=true
[EL Finest]: 2012-10-09 09:04:43.116--SessionBroker(2079047885)--Thread(Thread[SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1,5,main])--End predeploying Persistence Unit persistenceUnit; session file:/C:/Users/Minutis/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication4/build/classes/_persistenceUnit; state Predeployed; factoryCount 0
[EL Finer]: 2012-10-09 09:04:43.117--Thread(Thread[SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1,5,main])--JavaSECMPInitializer - transformer is null.
[EL Finest]: 2012-10-09 09:04:43.117--SessionBroker(2079047885)--Thread(Thread[SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1,5,main])--Begin predeploying Persistence Unit persistenceUnit; session file:/C:/Users/Minutis/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication4/build/classes/_persistenceUnit; state Predeployed; factoryCount 0
[EL Finest]: 2012-10-09 09:04:43.117--SessionBroker(2079047885)--Thread(Thread[SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1,5,main])--End predeploying Persistence Unit persistenceUnit; session file:/C:/Users/Minutis/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication4/build/classes/_persistenceUnit; state Predeployed; factoryCount 1
[EL Finest]: 2012-10-09 09:04:43.125--SessionBroker(2079047885)--Thread(Thread[SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1,5,main])--Begin deploying Persistence Unit persistenceUnit; session file:/C:/Users/Minutis/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication4/build/classes/_persistenceUnit; state Predeployed; factoryCount 1
[EL Finest]: 2012-10-09 09:04:43.128--SessionBroker(2079047885)--Thread(Thread[SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1,5,main])--property=eclipselink.logging.level; value=FINEST
[EL Finest]: 2012-10-09 09:04:43.128--SessionBroker(2079047885)--Thread(Thread[SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1,5,main])--property=eclipselink.logging.level; value=FINEST
[EL Info]: 2012-10-09 09:04:43.13--SessionBroker(2079047885)--Thread(Thread[SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1,5,main])--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504
[EL Info]: 2012-10-09 09:04:43.138--SessionBroker(2079047885)--Thread(Thread[SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1,5,main])--file:/C:/Users/Minutis/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication4/build/classes/_persistenceUnit login successful
[EL Warning]: 2012-10-09 09:04:43.146--Thread(Thread[SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1,5,main])--The collection of metamodel types is empty. Model classes may not have been found during entity search for Java SE and some Java EE container managed persistence units.  Please verify that your entity classes are referenced in persistence.xml using either <class> elements or a global <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> element
[EL Finer]: 2012-10-09 09:04:43.146--SessionBroker(2079047885)--Thread(Thread[SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1,5,main])--The collection of metamodel types is empty. Model classes may not have been found during entity search for Java SE and some Java EE container managed persistence units.  Please verify that your entity classes are referenced in persistence.xml using either <class> elements or a global <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> element
[EL Finest]: 2012-10-09 09:04:43.147--SessionBroker(2079047885)--Thread(Thread[SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1,5,main])--End deploying Persistence Unit persistenceUnit; session file:/C:/Users/Minutis/Documents/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication4/build/classes/_persistenceUnit; state Deployed; factoryCount 1
```

**EDIT 2:**

I figured that the problem is that persistence unit does not see any entities, although I declare them using class tags... Any help on this?

Comment: Did you find out how to user composite persistence unit with a single persistence.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting?  Or is it hanging?  If it is hanging, you need to break it and get the stack trace.

In general you need the , that is the only way to specify the child persistence units.  You don't need the classes to be in the jar files (although that is the easiest thing to do), you could just have the persistence.xml file in the jar.

Comment: The problem is that that composite persistence unit does not recognize any entities, although I declare them in composite persistence members (also tried in composite persistence unit -don't work) using <class> tags. See Warning in output message.

Comment: Hey, I am also facing the same issue. Did you found any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem, with a similar approach, but I'm stuck at the next step. I did solve this by creating the entities in another projects and then pasted them into the main project and finally including the entities in the persistance units (which I predefined into the persistence.xml. I'm redefining the databases in execution time). After that the entities were recognized, but the unit ' mixed' them a little.